# UIWebView back button not getting enabled

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiwebviewdelegate

In my application I have a `UIWebView` in which I need to add browser like functionality(*user can goBack,Forward or reload the page*). To achieve this I have used the code for this [tutorial.](http://iosdeveloperzone.com/2011/05/21/tutorial-building-a-web-browser-with-uiwebview-part-1/)

In my code I have only one change in `viewDidLoad`:

I am loading data from a local html file like this:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File name" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:NO];
NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
[self.webView loadData:htmlData MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
```

instead of:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://iosdeveloperzone.com"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

After loading initial html file if I am making any click on that page than the back button should get enabled, instead of its getting enabled after second url click and so that I am not able to go back to the original home page.

Please help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are telling in the last explanation. If you post some useful code related to back button or show some screenshot would be fine.

Comment: Here is the project http://iosdeveloperzone.com/tutorials/WebBrowser1.zip

Comment: @Dinesh Raja:and I have only one change in that I have already mentioned in question..(I am loading the webview from a html file)

Comment: Check out my answer and try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an answer. It's because you load data into the `webView` without `loadRequest`. If you `load data` into `webView` as a string, then it won't have any `url` to go back or load the old page. So it won't store the data you given to the `webView`. For that, you need to provide the `url` as like this.

```
[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File name" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];
```